# Chainer CNN- TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, chainer

I'm trying to run a classifier on Chainer, but failed due to the following error.

I have no idea about the error, because I confirmed that the iterator actually sent a batch to the trainer.

Is there a problem with the neural network model? Or, the way the data has been fed into the model is wrong?

Input.py

```
from chainer.datasets import split_dataset_random
from chainer.iterators import SerialIterator
from chainer.optimizers import Adam
from chainer.training import Trainer
from chainer.training.updaters import StandardUpdater
from chainer import functions as F, links as L
from chainer import Sequential

import numpy as np

batch_size = 3

X_train = np.ones((9957, 60, 80, 3), dtype=np.float32)
X_train, _ = split_dataset_random(X_train, 8000, seed=0)
train_iter = SerialIterator(X_train, batch_size)

model = Sequential(
    L.Convolution2D(None, 64, 3, 2),
    F.relu,
    L.Convolution2D(64, 32, 3, 2),
    F.relu,
    L.Linear(None, 16),
    F.dropout,
    L.Linear(16, 4)
)

model_loss = L.Classifier(model)
optimizer = Adam()
optimizer.setup(model_loss)
updater = StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer)
trainer = Trainer(updater, (25, 'epoch'))

trainer.run()
```

Stacktrace.py

```
Exception in main training loop: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 315, in run
    update()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 165, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 181, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, in_arrays)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 680, in update
    loss = lossfun(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 242, in __call__
    out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/links/model/classifier.py", line 143, in forward
    self.y = self.predictor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 242, in __call__
    out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/sequential.py", line 210, in forward
    x = layer(*x)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 242, in __call__
    out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/deploy/aaa.py", line 33, in <module>
    trainer.run()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 348, in run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 315, in run
    update()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 165, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 181, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, in_arrays)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 680, in update
    loss = lossfun(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 242, in __call__
    out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/links/model/classifier.py", line 143, in forward
    self.y = self.predictor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 242, in __call__
    out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/sequential.py", line 210, in forward
    x = layer(*x)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 242, in __call__
    out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Is there a problem with the neural network model or the way the data has been fed into the model? Please let me know if you need to see the whole code

Comment: Can you share the code you used which got the above error?

Comment: https://github.com/atom2k17/Blood-Cell/blob/master/BloodCell-chainer-checkpoint.ipynb

Comment: Could you update your question to write the code which you faced bug, explicitly? (instead of just pasting link to the code in comment)

Comment: I just found the reason of the exception, but this question is frozen. I wrote a minimal reproduction code and the solvency,and I’ｍ ready to post it on behalf of the questioner. The essential is the dataset: the dataset has to supply a tuple of int and ndarray instead of an ndarray for L.Classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you had to do is to give a tuple of `ndarray` and `int` to the model, because this is the specification of `L.Classifier`.

> Is there a problem with the neural network model? Or, the way the data has been fed into the model is wrong?

Therefore, the absolute answer is "the way the data has been fed in to the model is wrong".

In the following code, I defined a class inheriting `DatasetMixin` to feed a tuple of `ndarray` and `int`. (This is a conventional way how Chainer goes)

It should be noted that the input argument of `L.Convolution2D` must be an `ndarray` whose shape is (batch, channel, width, height). So I transpose the array in the dataset.

Solution.py

```
from chainer.datasets import split_dataset_random
from chainer.iterators import SerialIterator
from chainer.optimizers import Adam
from chainer.training import Trainer
from chainer.training.updaters import StandardUpdater
from chainer import functions as F, links as L
from chainer import Sequential

from chainer.dataset import DatasetMixin

import numpy as np


class MyDataset(DatasetMixin):
    def __init__(self, X, labels):
        super(MyDataset, self).__init__()
        self.X_ = X
        self.labels_ = labels
        self.size_ = X.shape[0]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size_

    def get_example(self, i):
        return np.transpose(self.X_[i, ...], (2, 0, 1)), self.labels_[i]


batch_size = 3

X_train = np.ones((9957, 60, 80, 3), dtype=np.float32)
label_train = np.random.randint(0, 4, (9957,), dtype=np.int32)
dataset = MyDataset(X_train, label_train)
dataset_train, _ = split_dataset_random(dataset, 8000, seed=0)
train_iter = SerialIterator(dataset_train, batch_size)

model = Sequential(
    L.Convolution2D(None, 64, 3, 2),
    F.relu,
    L.Convolution2D(64, 32, 3, 2),
    F.relu,
    L.Linear(None, 16),
    F.dropout,
    L.Linear(16, 4)
)

model_loss = L.Classifier(model)
optimizer = Adam()
optimizer.setup(model_loss)
updater = StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer)
trainer = Trainer(updater, (25, 'epoch'))

trainer.run()
```

Comment: I have run the program using the above code...running trainer.run() does not update the epoch details. Only when it is interrupted and run again it updates the details of the last epoch. And it does not finish the given set of epochs..it just shows that its still in progress.

Comment: epochs will be updated and all epochs will be completed when we put repeat=False when declaring valid_iter...

Comment: That is another issue. Please raise another question in StackOverflow if you want more help.

Comment: In line    X_train = np.ones((9957, 60, 80, 3), dtype=np.float32) if the input argument should be of shape (batchsize, channel, height, width) then is 9957 the batchsize? Or do I need to add batchsize to the ndarray?